# Dividing 3D Matrix into cubes

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D image represented as a 3D matrix.

Now I want to split the image up into cubes of size **`k x k x k`**, i.e. having a sliding cube on the image.

For each cube I want to do an operation on all the voxels inside it.

Of course, I can do it with 3 nested loops but it is not that simple because when the cube moves more than one dimension changes.

How would you do that? I would be very happy if somebody could provide some sample code. I'm doing it in MATLAB.

Comment: You can do one loop that loops over all elements, and then determine the location `(i,j,k)` of the element by using `mod`, etc.
I don't understand what you exactly mean by dividing, though. If you just want to apply a transformation to either part can't you access it by using `array(a:b,c:d,e:f)`?

Comment: Is the movement predefined?

Comment: The movement is not predefined but there should be no jumps and no overlappings, i.e. finally the image should be divided into cubes, so not a sliding window approach.

Comment: Or said in other words, I want to divide the 3D matrix into a grid.

Comment: Something like [blockproc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html)?

Comment: You may want to read **whathaveyoutried.com & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community**, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a **MCVE ( a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code ) showing what-you-have-tried so far**. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Contributing Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Comment: @user3666197 That's why I posed my comment as a question... Thomas, I'm still unclear on how the cubes are determined and you don't give any indication as to what the operation is to be performed on the cube. Both would be extremely helpful in providing a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put cube in a cell of a cell array you can do something like this.

```
%This is to randomly decide the size the of images so you can see it's general
n1 = randi(100);
n2 = randi(100);
n3 = randi(100);

%Make a substitute image
M = rand(n1, n2, n3);

%Then randomly choose a cube side length
k = randi(min([n1, n2, n3]));

%%% This is where your real code would start %%%
%%% Input your original image M and your voxel size k %%%
%%% If on the front end you ensure that you match you only need the last line but, I put the preprocessing in as a precaution. %%%

% Get the size of the matrix
[n1, n2, n3] = size(M);

%Pad the images to make them equally divide into your cube
MPrime = zeros(k - mod(n1, k) + n1, k - mod(n2, k) + n2, k - mod(n3, k) + n3);

%Put the image into the padded storage
MPrime(1:n1, 1:n2, 1:n3) = M;

%Split up the voxels into their cubes
MBoxed = mat2cell(MPrime, k*ones(size(MPrime, 1)/k, 1), k*ones(size(MPrime, 2)/k, 1), k*ones(size(MPrime, 3)/k, 1));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't want to put each voxel into a cell. A cell should span several voxels and the cell should be a cube (i.e. in 3D).

Comment: Sorry, I did not use the correct terminology. Each cell has a k * k * k cube of voxels in it.